# How to determine pixel size of a text box in InDesign?

Tags: text

This may be a basic question... but in InDesign, how does one determine the pixel size of a text box?

Specifically, we need to write text to specifications of 600 pixel width, and have no idea

a) how to scale a text box to specific pixel width,

b) how to determine what word count we can fit in, and

c) how to do it in a table?

Answer (score 2):

The **Info Panel** in InDesign will show you the width and height of a text frame.

[image]

You can also alter these measurements, with the text frame selected, in the **Control/Options Panel** across the top of the screen.

[image]

As for **character and/or word count**.... as @Vnovak pointed out... it depends upon size, face, etc of the type. There's no blanket answer for this.

Regarding the **table**... I don't understand this. If you are wanting to create a table with this information, i.e.:

- 50px by 100px text frame holds X words
- 100px by 150px text frame holds X words

That's not really possible due to the variation of the word count. You can certainly set up a table easily, but there's no way to get the word count for each size - 24pt Helvetica is going to allow less words than 10pt Myriad Condensed.

Answer (score 0):

Lisa, 
a) you can specify any width in any values in Width field at top panel. For example just type 600px. You even can do simple math there, e.g. 600/2px or 200+185in

b) word count to fit in type box? a bit odd questions, because it depends by so many things - weight of box, font size, font style, leading, language, etc, etc..

c) here is guide for you about tables in inDesign http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6ff5a.html

Comment: Lisa, was it helpful?